# hornetq restart overrides the log files

Tags: hornetq

hornetq restart overrides the log files,although the log file rotation is working fine, I am using the following config, I am running hornet in a standalone clustered mode

`# File handler configuration
handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=DEBUG
handler.FILE.properties=autoFlush,fileName,suffix,append
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.fileName=../logs/hornetq.log
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN`

Answer (score 2):

found out the issue, the order of the properties matter!

```
# File handler configuration
handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=DEBUG
handler.FILE.properties=autoFlush,append,fileName,suffix
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.fileName=../logs/hornetq.log
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN
```

https://community.jboss.org/message/742699